# How to put my position on center and hide some markers

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here I have a google map/places code which show me my position and markers with opening_hours
http://jsbin.com/ATaZEXE/12/edit

First I want to when I search put my position on center of screen. How I have this code:

```
if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map,
        position: pos,
        content: 'Here you are.'
      });

      map.setCenter(pos);
    });
  }
```

but when I search for some objects, my position isnt on center, How to make it to be on center of screen?

Second:

I want to hide marker that dont contain opening_hours. So I have:

```
 (function(marker,request,i){
        setTimeout(function(){
         service.getDetails(request, function(place, status){
          try{
            var time=place.opening_hours.periods[1].open.time;
            var closed=place.opening_hours.periods[1].close.time;
            var closed=[(closed/100).toFixed(0),closed.substr(-2)].join(':');
            marker.set('labelContent',[(time/100).toFixed(0),time.substr(-2)].join(':')+' - '+closed+'</br>'+place.name);

marker.set('labelClass', place.opening_hours.open_now ? "labels" : "labels closed");

          }
          catch(e){}
         });
        },
        i*250)
      })(marker,request,i);
```

and I try to hide markers that dont have opening_hours with:

```
(function(marker,request,i){
        setTimeout(function(){
         service.getDetails(request, function(place, status){
          try{
            var time=place.opening_hours.periods[1].open.time;
            var closed=place.opening_hours.periods[1].close.time;
            var closed=[(closed/100).toFixed(0),closed.substr(-2)].join(':');
            marker.set('labelContent',[(time/100).toFixed(0),time.substr(-2)].join(':')+' - '+closed+'</br>'+place.name);

if(!place.opening_hours.open_now)marker.set(null);

marker.set('labelClass', place.opening_hours.open_now ? "labels" : "labels closed");

          }
          catch(e){}
         });
        },
        i*250)
      })(marker,request,i);
```

Comment: Is there any solution here?

Answer (score 0):

you can hide markers by using

```
marker.setMap(null);
```